# Is their any way that can divide each element of a list with each element of another list on python

Tags: python

```
list_1 = [10,12,16,20]
list_2 = [2,9,5,3,6]

division  = []
for x in list_1 :
    division.append (list_2/x)

print (division)
```

I tried this but it give me error
And what I want is I don't want to import any external modules numpy or others

Comment: Please, re-write your question's title to be more concise and clear. Revise your writing and try to understand the people who will read your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip()` builtin method:

```
list_1 = [10,12,16,20]
list_2 = [2,9,5,3,6]

division  = []
for e1, e2 in zip(list_1, list_2):
    division.append(e2 / e1)

print(division)
```

Prints:

```
[0.2, 0.75, 0.3125, 0.15]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `map` following way:

```
list_1 = [10,12,16,20]
list_2 = [2,9,5,3,6]
division  = list(map(lambda x,y:x/y,list_2,list_1))
print(division)
```

Output:

```
[0.2, 0.75, 0.3125, 0.15]
```

`map` accept function and iterables, I did used anonymous function (lambda) accepting two arguments which returns effect of its division and `list_2` and `list_1`. `map` does apply that function to elements corresponding to each other and give iterator which I convert to `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
list_1 = [10,12,16,20]
list_2 = [2,9,5,3,6]
division  = []

for x in list_1:
  for y in list_2:
    division.append(y/x)

print(division)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide elements of the first list by elements at the same position in the other list, you can use zip in a list comprehension:

```
listA = [10,12,16,20]
listB = [2,9,5,3,6]
divisions = [ a/b for a,b in zip(listA,listB) ]
print(divisions)
# [5.0, 1.3333333333333333, 3.2, 6.666666666666667]
```

if you really want to divide each element of the first list by EVERY element of the other list, then use a two level list comprehension:

```
divisions = [ a/b for a in listA for b in listB ]
print(divisions)
# [5.0, 1.1111111111111112, 2.0, 3.3333333333333335, 1.6666666666666667, 6.0, 1.3333333333333333, 2.4, 4.0, 2.0, 8.0, 1.7777777777777777, 3.2, 5.333333333333333, 2.6666666666666665, 10.0, 2.2222222222222223, 4.0, 6.666666666666667, 3.3333333333333335]
```